Why a non-null warning on a nullable property?
Here's my code that declares & sets ReturnUrl.
public class ExPageBase : ExComponentBase
{
    [Parameter]
    [SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "returnUrl")]
    public string? ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    [MemberNotNull (nameof(ReturnUrl))]
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        await base.OnInitializedAsync();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReturnUrl))
        {
            if (Principal.IsSysAdmin())
                ReturnUrl = GlobalConstants.UrlSysAdminHomePage;
            else if (Principal.IsManager())
                ReturnUrl = GlobalConstants.UrlManagerHomePage;
            else if (Principal.IsOnlyVolunteer())
                ReturnUrl = GlobalConstants.UrlVolunteerHomePage;
            else
                ReturnUrl = GlobalConstants.UrlHomePage;
        }
    }
}

I am getting the following warning when I compile:
5>C:\Git\LouisHowe\LouisHowe.web\Shared\ExPageBase.cs(51,4,51,35): warning CS8774: Member 'ReturnUrl' must have a non-null value when exiting.

Line 51 is: await base.OnInitializedAsync();
Why does it say that ReturnUrl must have a non-null value anywhere for any reason?
And why in particular when exiting a call to the base OnInitializedAsync() when I am still inside my OnInitializedAsync()?
I can understand it giving me a warning due to the MemberNotNull when exiting from my OnInitializedAsync(). But why from calling the base one?
This code is for Blazor Interactive Server although I think that is irrelevant to this question.
Update: I have a ton of code that calls await base.OnInitializedAsync() where it is calling the above OnInitializedAsync. All that code complains about ReturnUrl being null if I don't use MemberNotNull.
In addition, I need in the above code to call the base. OnInitializedAsync first as it populates the Principal object.

async-await returns before then

@DanielA.White And does that mean it needs to be set before the task it returns completes? Thank you, I had assumed that any promises from a method were only valid after the task it returns completes. If you write this as an answer, happy to accept it.

https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/4994

@DanielA.White Follow-on question. I need to call the base method first because it populates the Principal property I use to set ReturnUrl. What should I do when ReturnUrl will not be set until the method completes?

You can't use MemberNotNull in that case, so just remove it. "promises from a method were only valid after the task it returns completes" -- that is definitely not the case, these things are functions returning objects. The fact that you might (or might not) call its continuation makes no difference, the function returns at the first await, and that's when your static analysis attributes have to be fully complied with.

@Blindy I see your point and it makes sense. Is there an attribute that says NotNull when the called method completes? And then any code after that call to await Method() knows it is not null once the await completes? Or is this getting too complex and so having a NotNull for this case would be problematic? And again, happy to select an answer that lays this out as I think others will find this useful. TIA

There is no such attribute. However I don't think it's too complex either, it's more a matter of whether or not it makes sense. You should open an issue with this suggestion on the static analysis github project and get feedback on it.

@Blindy I voted for it - https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/5657
